# closing tkinter window together with messagebox error window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

In my script I sometimes call my `ErrorWindow` class to show an error message. This creates an empty `tkinter` window and a `messagebox` error window. I either only want the `messagebox` window, or I want the `tkinter` window to close automatically when I close the error window.
I've tried two pieces of code:

```
class ErrorWindow:
    def __init__(self,error_message):
        self.error_window = tk.Tk()
        messagebox.showerror("ERROR",error_message,command=self.close)
        self.error_window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close)
        self.error_window.mainloop()

    def close(self):
        self.error_window.destroy()
```

.

```
class ErrorWindow:
    def __init__(self,error_message):

        messagebox.showerror("ERROR",error_message) #automatically creates a tk window too
```

But even with the second one, the `tkinter` window remains after I close the `messagebox`.

How can I program the class so that I only have to press a button (either `Ok` or the `X` in the top right of a window) once to close all windows (whether that is one or two)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify whether there is just one place or multiple places where you might want want an error message.  If the latter, you can create and withdraw a tk window just once.  I believe a wrapper function rather than class should be sufficient for your purposes.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tk.Tk()
# consider placing root to control where messagebox appears
root.withdraw()

def showerror(message):
    messagebox.showerror('XYZ ERROR', message, parent=root)
```

To avoid possible problems, I always use an explicit `master` or `parent` for everything and never depend on `_default_root`.

Comment: So this will keep a tkinter window open during the whole program, which in turn is the parent for each error message opened?

Comment: @RnRoger I am not sure what you mean by 'open', but yes, it will keep the undisplayed, invisible, Tk *object* in existence during the whole program and available as master and parent widget.  IDLE currently works this way: a withdrawn root Tk instance is the master for the visible Toplevel instances.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `withdraw` the main window:

```
class ErrorWindow:
    def __init__(self,error_message):
        if not tk._default_root: # check for existing Tk instance
            error_window = tk.Tk()
            error_window.withdraw()
        messagebox.showerror("ERROR",error_message)
```

This has no business as a class. You should remake this a simple function.

Comment: you also need to remember to destroy it, or every time a new window is called you create another and another and another...

Answer (score 1):

The small function below will do the job. By setting the type you can choose for: info, warning or error message box, the default is 'Info'. You can set also the timeout, the default is 2.5 seconds.

```py
def showMessage(message, type='info', timeout=2500):
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import messagebox as msgb

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    try:
        root.after(timeout, root.destroy)
        if type == 'info':
            msgb.showinfo('Info', message, master=root)
        elif type == 'warning':
            msgb.showwarning('Warning', message, master=root)
        elif type == 'error':
            msgb.showerror('Error', message, master=root)
    except:
        pass
```

Call the function as follow:
For message type 'Info' and timeout of 2.5 seconds:

```py
showMessage('Your message')
```

Or by your own settings for type message 'Error' and timeout 4 seconds:

```py
showMessage('Your message', type='error', timeout=4000)
```